# как найти в блоке и получить выбранный радио баттон?

Tags: jquery

```js
$(".next").click(function () {
  var selectAnswers = $(this).closest('block-test');
});
```

```html
        <div class="block-test >
                <h2>{{$question->question}}</h2>
                <div class="wrap-options">
                   <div class="options">
                      <h3>{!!$question->example!!}</h3>
                      <div class="wrap-option">
                          <input class="option" type="radio" name="option" value="a"><h3 class="option">{{$question->a}}</h3>
                      </div>
                      <div class="wrap-option">
                          <input class="option" type="radio" name="option" value="b"><h3 class="option">{{$question->b}}</h3>
                      </div>
                      <div class="wrap-option">
                          <input class="option" type="radio" name="option" value="c"><h3 class="option">{{$question->c}}</h3>
                      </div>
                      <div class="wrap-option">
                        @if($question->d)
                        <input class="option" type="radio" name="option" value="d"><h3 class="option">{{$question->d}}</h3>
                        @endif
                      </div>  
                   </div>
                </div>
                <button type="button" data-order="{{$question->order}}" class="btn btn-info next">Next</button>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто достаточно использовать jQuery [:checked](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) селектор, и обратите внимание, что у вас ошибка в DOM дереве, в ответе исправленный вариант, не закрывается атрибут `class` в `<div class="block-test">`

```js
$(".next").click(function () {
  const selectAnswer = $(this).closest('.block-test').find('input[type="radio"].option:checked').val();
  console.log(selectAnswer);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block-test">
                <h2>{{$question->question}}</h2>
                <div class="wrap-options">
                   <div class="options">
                      <h3>{!!$question->example!!}</h3>
                      <div class="wrap-option">
                          <input class="option" type="radio" name="option" value="a"><h3 class="option">{{$question->a}}</h3>
                      </div>
                      <div class="wrap-option">
                          <input class="option" type="radio" name="option" value="b"><h3 class="option">{{$question->b}}</h3>
                      </div>
                      <div class="wrap-option">
                          <input class="option" type="radio" name="option" value="c"><h3 class="option">{{$question->c}}</h3>
                      </div>
                      <div class="wrap-option">
                        @if($question->d)
                        <input class="option" type="radio" name="option" value="d"><h3 class="option">{{$question->d}}</h3>
                        @endif
                      </div>  
                   </div>
                </div>
                <button type="button" data-order="{{$question->order}}" class="btn btn-info next">Next</button>
            </div>
```

Comment: Yaroslav Molchan спасибо !!!